# Product of the LU Factorisation - Correct Formula?

Tags: matrices, notation, matrix-decomposition

Let's say I have:

$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2 &3 \\ 
0 &1 &1.3 \\ 
0& 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
L = \begin{bmatrix} 
10 & 0 & 0 \\
40 & -30 & 0 \\
10 & 30 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to show how I have calculated the determinant (taking the product of the diagonal elements of $U$ multiplied by the product of the diagonal product of $L$) in an elegant way. Does the following represent this:

$$Det(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} diag(U) \cdot diag(L)$$

I am sure there is a more "elegant" and "optimal" way to represent what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Amzoti No $A = {10, 20, 30; 40, 50, 80, 10, 50, 80}$ I think I have the $U$ and $L$ the wrong way around because the determinant result is $-3000$

Comment: @Amzoti - I get you now. I should only take the product of the $diag(L)$ because the $u$ contains just 1's along the diagonal line and these can be ignored?

Comment: @Amzoti - with that in mind, would this then be an elegant solution/equation for this?